# How to Convert this Query to Eloquent or Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a query like this. How should I convert it into a eloquent or query builder

```
SELECT
x.MATERIAL_ID,
(SELECT TAPET_NAME FROM MA_TAPE_TYPE WHERE TAPET_CODE = x.MATERIAL_TYPE) as media_type,
(SELECT TAPEF_NAME FROM MA_TAPE_FORMAT WHERE TAPEF_CODE = x.MATERIAL_FORMAT) as media_format,
STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.HOUSE_NO,
x.TXN_DATE,
STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.PROGRAM_NAME,
CASE WHEN x.iden_flag = 'P' THEN STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.epi_title WHEN x.iden_flag = 'C'
THEN STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.prod_version_name WHEN x.iden_flag = 'M' THEN STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.promo_name 
END as episode_title,
PUR_EPISODE_HDR.EPI_NO,
(SELECT MAX (last_date) FROM run_master WHERE run_master.row_id_epi = PUR_EPISODE_HDR.row_id AND 
run_master.run_aired = 'Y') as last_tx,
x.REMARKS,
x.LOCATION_ID as shelf_no,
stock_material_slag.remarks as short_list
FROM STOCK_MATERIAL x
LEFT JOIN STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI ON x.MATERIAL_ID = STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.MATERIAL_ID
LEFT JOIN stock_material_slag ON x.MATERIAL_ID = stock_material_slag.MATERIAL_ID
LEFT JOIN PUR_EPISODE_HDR ON STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.ROW_ID_EPI = PUR_EPISODE_HDR.ROW_ID
```

I'm confused as to how to convert them. Can someone help me.

I tried to write like this.
But it doesn't work,

```
$materials = DB::connection('oracle')
             ->table('STOCK_MATERIAL AS x')
             ->select('x.MATERIAL_ID',
                     DB::raw("(SELECT TAPET_NAME FROM MA_TAPE_TYPE WHERE TAPET_CODE = x.MATERIAL_TYPE) as MEDIA_TYPE"),
                     DB::raw("(SELECT TAPEF_NAME FROM MA_TAPE_FORMAT WHERE TAPEF_CODE = x.MATERIAL_FORMAT) as MEDIA_FORMAT"),
                     'x.TXN_DATE',
                     'y.HOUSE_NO', 'y.PROGRAM_NAME',
                     DB::raw("(CASE WHEN x.IDEN_FLAG = 'P' THEN z.EPI_TITLE WHEN x.IDEN_FLAG = 'C' THEN z.PROD_VERSION_NAME WHEN x.IDEN_FLAG = 'M' THEN z.PROMO_NAME END as EPISODE_TITLE)"),
                     'w.EPI_NO',
                     DB::raw("(SELECT MAX (LAST_DATE) FROM RUN_MASTER WHERE RUN_MASTER.ROW_ID_EPI = w.ROW_ID AND RUN_MASTER.RUN_AIRED = 'Y') as LAST_TX"),
                     'z.REMARKS',
                     'x.LOCATION_ID as SHELF_NO',
                     'z.REMARKS'
                     )
             ->leftJoin('STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI AS y', 'y.MATERIAL_ID', '=', 'x.MATERIAL_ID')
             ->leftJoin('STOCK_MATERIAL_SLAG AS z', 'z.MATERIAL_ID', '=', 'x.MATERIAL_ID')
             ->leftJoin('PUR_EPISODE_HDR AS w', 'w.ROW_ID', '=', 'y.ROW_ID_EPI')
```

What else do I write right?

Comment: Do you have eloquent models such as StockMaterialEpi?

Comment: Yes, i have.. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define eloquent models and then use `with()`. Documentation can be found at the link below: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

example

```
StockMaterial::with([
  'maTapeType' => function($query) {
    $query->get('name')
  })
])
```

For Query Builder you DB::raw and DB::leftJoin to create the same query.

```
DB::from('STOCK_MATERIAL')
  ->selectRaw([
    'TAPET_NAME as media_type',
    'CASE WHEN x.iden_flag = "P" THEN STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.epi_title 
       WHEN x.iden_flag = "C" THEN STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.prod_version_name 
       WHEN x.iden_flag = "M" THEN STOCK_MATERIAL_EPI.promo_name 
     END as episode_title',
  ])
  ->leftJoin('MA_TAPE_TYPE', 'TAPET_CODE', 'STOCK_MATERIAL.MATERIAL_TYPE')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-expressions
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins

Comment: Actually I've read the documentation. But I'm still confused as to how.

Can you help me to write it into eloquent or query builder?

Comment: I have given you example on how to do it either using eloquent or query builder. In both cases you'd need to use selectRaw. Your query can be improved tho

Comment: Also, it would be good to know what issue you are experiencing... judging by your example code you have made some good progress.

Comment: So, should I use selectRaw instead of DB:: Raw as I used?

Comment: I suggest selectRaw when we have to use DB::raw too many times, that way laravel does most of the work for you and less copy and paste on your part